# Prevent Duplicate SQL entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, duplicates

I want to be able to prevent duplicate SQL text field rows. That is, if row 1 has the name field already defined as "John Smith", I don't want it to be able to add another "John Smith" (as common as that name might be).

I tried checking if it existed at time of insertion, but the problem is, if you open up two browser windows at the same time and click submit simultaneously, they'll both check, the check will clear, and then they'll both insert if it's close enough together.

Oh, and this is on a PHP site.

Thanks!

Comment: can you use a unique index on the field in mysql? then when php does an insert handle the duplicate entry error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxname ON tablename (fieldname);
```

Adding this index will ensure that no duplicate entries for `fieldname` field will be recorded into `tablename` table.

You will get a MySQL error with the second client. You should handle this in your PHP code, and put up the form again (instead of just displaying the error message).

An other possibility (for more complex sitations) is the `LOCK` functionality. If you lock the table before checking and then you insert your record a concurrent operation (in the second browser window) will be delayed until you release the locks. Then the record will be already saved, so the second PHP script will *see it* and handle the sitation.

Comment: The extra plus side to this is most database vendors will trigger a specific error for a unique constraint violation which means you can catch it in your script

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! Works great with my existing code since it'll kick it to a page saying you've already done it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` can also be used to select unique rows.

```
...
select distinct *
  from table1
...
```