# duplicate entry in SQL table

Tags: php, sql

I am making a subscribers entry form (html), the problem that i am facing is I want to check if the entered email ID already exists in the table. I do not want to make it primary key.
I tried searching online, but all I got was how to delete the data from the database. I want to know if it can be done when the submit button is clicked

Comment: make email id unique key

Comment: You got to be more specific about environment and what options you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Duplicate SQL entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412669/prevent-duplicate-sql-entries)

Comment: `num_rows` <= mysqli / `rowCount()` <= PDO. Show your code; this is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal is to use a primary key or unique index. But if you do not want to use primary key, then you can try something like:

1. Get email id from user from the form data.
2. On click of submit, a server side code can be called to:

   - Check if the email id already exists in DB.
   - If exists, then do not insert OR update record (as per your logic) and show error/alert message to user.
   - If not exists, then insert the record in DB.

If not validating on form submit,Not sure of PHP, but in jsp, we use AJAX requests to validate if the email address is already available. Only if the email address is unique, you will be allowed to submit the form.

Comment: why don't you advice OP to make email column a unique index in database table? Should be one of your steps maybe.

Comment: @iroegbu: Included unique index in my response.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have a query fired on server once you click on Submit button.

Select [records] from [tablename] where email_ID is "entered by user."

If this query returns a record, that ID exists else you are good to go with new one.